# How to get current router url beforeunload on angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to store the current router url when the user clicks on browser refresh on an angular application. I need it since we have a SSO mechanism which is doing redirection and which can only be configured to redirect to the root page. So I have a processing in app.component.ts which is handling the proper internal routing from a route stored in the session storage. I would like to ensure the user is then going back to the proper route he left when he refreshes the page (and that the SSO mecanism is redirecting him to the root page). I was thinking on saving in the session storage the current route when there is a browser refresh this way:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeUnloadHander(_event) {
    console.log(this.router.url);
    // store in session storage the router.url
  }
```

The problem is that, whatever route i am on, console.log(this.router.url) is containing '/' instead of the proper current route. Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use Router in an external Service like :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RouterExtService {
  
  private previousUrl: string = undefined;
  private currentUrl: string = undefined;

  constructor(private router : Router) {
    this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
    router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log(this.previousUrl, this.currentUrl)
        this.previousUrl = this.currentUrl;
        this.currentUrl = event.url;
      };
    });
  }
```

You'll get the url of your current route with 'event.url' and store it.

Hope it helps